# How can I change the IIS default document order using Powershell?

Tags: iis, powershell

How can I make sure *default.aspx* is the first default document for my IIS website?

I have tried:

```
Add-WebConfiguration //defaultDocument/files "IIS:\sites\Default Web Site\MyWebSite" -atIndex 0 -Value @{value="Default.aspx"}
```

but if *default.aspx* is already in the list it complains

```
Add-WebConfiguration : Filename: 
Error: Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'add' with unique key attribute 'value' set to 'Default.aspx'
```

How can I add it if necessary and move it to the top of the list if it's not already there?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The trick is to remove 'default.aspx' if it is already anywhere in the list:

```
$filter = "system.webserver/defaultdocument/files"
$site = "IIS:\sites\Default Web Site\MyWebSite"
$file = "default.aspx"

if ((Get-WebConfiguration $filter/* "$site" | where {$_.value -eq $file}).length -eq 1)
{
   Remove-WebconfigurationProperty $filter "$site" -name collection -AtElement @{value=$file}
}

Add-WebConfiguration $filter "$site" -atIndex 0 -Value @{value=$file}
```

We first check for the existence of default.aspx, if found, remove it and then add it back in at the top, just like you already did.

Comment: With this I receive an error when there is a duplicate: **Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'add' with unique key attribute 'value' set to 'Default.aspx'**. It seems to be happening at `Get-WebConfiguration` cmdlet

Comment: @ganjeli - this happens when there already is a default.aspx entry at the server level. I can't tell how to fix this as have no PC for several weeks.

Answer (score 1):

For those that may find it useful: I wanted to configure IIS such that the `default.aspx` is the first default document for the web server. Here is the script if that's what you want to do:

```
#requires -RunAsAdministrator

$file = "default.aspx"
$baseFilter = "/system.webServer/defaultDocument/files"

$filter = "{0}/add[@value='{1}']" -f $baseFilter,$file
$fileExists = $null -ne (Get-WebConfigurationProperty $filter -Name ".")
$updateConfig = -not $fileExists
if ( $fileExists ) {
  $firstValue = Get-WebConfiguration "$baseFilter/*" |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty value -First 1
  $updateConfig = $firstValue -ne $file
  if ( $updateConfig ) {
    Clear-WebConfiguration $filter -Verbose
  }
}
if ( $updateConfig ) {
  Add-WebConfiguration $baseFilter -AtIndex 0 -Value @{value = $file} -Verbose
}
```

The script checks if `default.aspx` is set as a default document. If `default.aspx` is a default document, it checks if it's first in the list. If `default.aspx` is in the list but not first, the script removes it. If `default.aspx` is not set as a default document or it's not first in the list, the script adds it as the first in the list.

The above script is the IIS GUI configuration equivalent of clicking the server node, double-clicking `Default Document` in the right pane, and moving `default.aspx` to the first position (or adding it in the first position if it's not in the list).